# How to retrive comma seaparated values from database?

Tags: php

I want to retrieve comma separated values from a database and store each value in a variable.

For example: in my column I have the following: `2,3,5,8,9,21`

I'd like to store the numbers inside variables like this:

```
$a=2
$b=3
$c=5 
// and so on…
```

Comment: Depending on what you actually want to do with the data and on your dbms you might want to consider [nomalizing your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look on below solutions:

**Method 1**

```
$alphabet = range('a', 'z');
$str = '2,3,5,8,9,21';
$str_array = explode(',', $str);
foreach($str_array as $k=>$v){
    ${$alphabet[$k]} = $v;
}

echo $a,$b,$c,$d;
```

**Method 2**

```
$var = 'a';

$str = '2,3,5,8,9,21';
$str_array = explode(',', $str);
foreach($str_array as $k=>$v){
    ${$var} = $v;
    ++$var;
}
echo $a,$b,$c,$d;
```

both solution's output:

```
2358
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna load the string that contain integers separated with ',' or '.' or 'a' or ';' do:

- If you wanna go for ',':

  $char = ',';
- If you wanna go for '.':

  $char = '.';
- If you wanna go for 'a':

  $char = 'a';
- If you wanna go for ';':

  $char = ';';

(I added this to help anyone that have any other syntax of string)

To connect you can do([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)):

```
$connection = mysql_connect('adress', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

Okay, we have connection. Now take the data ([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)).

```
$database = "DatabaseWithTableWithIntegers";
$table = "TableWithIntegers";
$rowname = "RowWithIntegers";
$sql = "USE $database; SELECT $rowname FROM $table;";
$result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection);
```

Now declare something like list:

```
$arr = []; // array for fetching
$vrr = []; // array for fetched
```

Next step is to fetch rows([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
```

Row have string like "2,142,124,53,3511,513,531,53" if separator was an "," and the record exists in database/table.
The magical function is explode, it slices all the segments into an array([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)):

```
$arr = explode($char, $row[$rowname]); //rowname is to be 100% sure
```

The last thing is to do the conversion([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php))

```
for($arr as &$a){
$value = intval($a);
array_push($vrr, $value); // to save the value into vrr([Documentation][6])
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am new to php please give me full code

Comment: I can copy it when I arrive home, smartphone is very last code editor (eta 4h)

Comment: Hope, now it's clear

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated and is not safe to use it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are storing data in form of a1,a2,a3 in a single column, why don't you just fetch the data and split it using `explode()` method?

if you are using associative array, then use `json_encode()` when storing the data as string, and then decode it using `json_decode()` after fetched from database